# Removing substring from list of strings

Tags: python, pandas, substring

I have the column of values as below,

```
array(['Mar 2018', 'Jun 2018', 'Sep 2018', 'Dec 2018', 'Mar 2019',
       'Jun 2019', 'Sep 2019', 'Dec 2019', 'Mar 2020', 'Jun 2020',
       'Sep 2020', 'Dec 2020'], dtype=object)
```

From this values I require output as,

```
array(['Mar'18', 'Jun'18', 'Sep'18', 'Dec'18', 'Mar'19',
       'Jun'19', 'Sep'19', 'Dec'19', 'Mar'20', 'Jun'20',
       'Sep'20', 'Dec'20'], dtype=object)
```

I have tried with following code,

```
df['Period'] = df['Period'].replace({'20','''})
```

But here it wasnt converting , how to replace the same?

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following.

```
df['Period'].replace(r" \d{2}", "'", regex=True)
```

Output will be as follows.

```
0   Mar'18
1   Jun'18
2   Sep'18
3   Dec'18
4   Mar'19
5   Jun'19
6   Sep'19
7   Dec'19
8   Mar'20
9   Jun'20
10  Sep'20
11  Dec'20
```

Comment: where can I refer to regex characters. Any links for refering to the same, so that it may be useful for me in future?

Comment: @Krish1992, you mean for learning regex, if yes then use following https://www.regexbuddy.com/ site, I always refer the same, its GREAT knowledge there. Cheers and happy learning :)

Answer (score 2):

try this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/6y2Kai/1):

```py
df['Period'].str.replace(r"\s\d{2}(\d{2})", r"'\1", regex=True)
```

in the replacement part, `\1` refers to the capturing group, which is the last two digits in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Following your code (slightly changed to work) will not get you what you need as it will replace all '20's.

```
>>> df['Period'] = df['Period'].str.replace('20','')

Out[179]: 
    Period
0   Mar 18
1   Jun 18
2   Sep 18
3   Dec 18
4   Mar 19
5   Jun 19
6   Sep 19
7   Dec 19
8     Mar 
9     Jun 
10    Sep 
11    Dec
```

Another way without using `regex`, would be with with vectorized `str` methods, more [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html):

```
df['Period_refined'] = df['Period'].str[:3] + "'" + df['Period'].str[-2:]
```

**Output**

```
df

      Period Period_refined
0   Mar 2018         Mar'18
1   Jun 2018         Jun'18
2   Sep 2018         Sep'18
3   Dec 2018         Dec'18
4   Mar 2019         Mar'19
5   Jun 2019         Jun'19
6   Sep 2019         Sep'19
7   Dec 2019         Dec'19
8   Mar 2020         Mar'20
9   Jun 2020         Jun'20
10  Sep 2020         Sep'20
11  Dec 2020         Dec'20
```

Comment: upvoted for the non-regex solution, but where is the `'` :)